# Matrix of Hamiltonian $H=\frac{ħω}{2}(|1〉〈1|−|2〉〈2|)+\frac{iħχ}{2}(|1〉〈2|−|2〉〈1|)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, linear-algebra, two-level-system

I have a second order system, with a Hamiltonian $$H=\frac{ħω}{2}(|1〉〈1|−|2〉〈2|)+\frac{iħχ}{2}(|1〉〈2|−|2〉〈1|)$$ where $|1〉,|2〉$ form a complete basis for the system. I'm trying to get the matrix that represents H in this system, but am unsure how to go about it. Am I supposed to treat the basis vectors generally? ie $|1〉=(a_1+ib_1, a_2+ib_2)^T$, and similarly for $|2〉$. Where I then expand out and simplify?

Cheers for any help.

Comment: Choose an orthogonal basis of dimension 2.

Comment: Each matrix element is just given by $H_{m,n}=\langle m|H|n\rangle$. Just check any of your intro QM or linear algebra texts :)

Comment: With basis you mean orthonormal basis? The basically you can take (1,0) and (0,1) as basis vector representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 \rvert}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}
\newcommand{\bracket}[2]{\langle #1 \vert #2 \rangle}
$

You said your vectors $\ket 1$ and $\ket 2$ form a complete basis.
I assume they are also meant to be orthonormal, i.e.
$$
\begin{align}
\bracket 1 1 = 1 \\
\bracket 1 2 = 0 \\
\bracket 2 1 = 0 \\
\bracket 2 2 = 1
\end{align}
\tag{1}$$

Given your Hamiltonian
$$
H = \frac{\hbar\omega}{2} (\ket{1}\bra{1} - \ket{2}\bra{2})
  + \frac{i\hbar\chi}{2}  (\ket{1}\bra{2} - \ket{2}\bra{1})
\tag{2}$$

it is straight-forward to get the matrix elements by their definition $H_{mn} = \bra{m}H\ket{n}$.

For example
$$
\begin{align}
H_{11} &= \bra{1}H\ket{1} \\
 &= \bra{1}\left( \frac{\hbar\omega}{2} (\ket{1}\bra{1} - \ket{2}\bra{2})
   + \frac{i\hbar\chi}{2}  (\ket{1}\bra{2} - \ket{2}\bra{1}) \right) \ket{1}  \\
 &= \frac{\hbar\omega}{2}
\end{align}
$$

In the last step above you expand the product, and by observing the
orthonormality relations (1) most terms of the resulting sum are zero.
Only one term remains.

In a similar manner you get
$$
\begin{align}
H_{12} = \bra{1}H\ket{2} &=  \frac{i\hbar \chi}{2} \\
H_{21} = \bra{2}H\ket{1} &= -\frac{i\hbar \chi}{2} \\
H_{22} = \bra{2}H\ket{2} &= -\frac{\hbar \omega}{2}
\end{align}
$$

or written as matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix} H_{11} & H_{12} \\ H_{21} & H_{22} \end{pmatrix}
= \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix} \omega & i\chi \\ -i\chi & -\omega \end{pmatrix}
$$

Let me add some clarification about *representation*, since I got
the impression that there was some confusion what this actually means.
The Hamiltonian $H$ is represented by this matrix
$\begin{pmatrix} H_{11} & H_{12} \\ H_{21} & H_{22} \end{pmatrix}$.
The basis state $\ket 1$ is simply represented by the column vector
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$,
and $\ket 2$ is represented by $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.
A general state $\ket \psi$ would be represented by
$\begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix}$.